Is there a ring whose unit group is the $p$-Prüfer group?
My professor said “not every group is actually the unit group of some ring” even though some are.
He gave us examples, like $(\mathbb Z/2, +)$ being the unit group of $(\mathbb Z/4 , +, ·)$, while he gave us a beautiful proof for $(\mathbb Z/5, +)$ not being any ring’s unit group… though he continued that the $p$-Prüfer group $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}$ is the unit group of a ring as well but didn’t add much more as we weren’t familiar with this group back then. The course ended, I’m back home and I can’t ask him anymore till after the exam next month, so I was wondering if someone knew the answer.
thanks in advance.
edit: just found out i can also present $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}$ as $\{e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{p^n}} \ | \ k \in \mathbb Z, n \in \mathbb N \} $ which is basically a subgroup of $ ( \mathbb C^{\times}, · )$, can’t i just quotient $ ( \mathbb C, +, · )$ over something to get what i want? seems not, visually.

The non-existence of a 2-torsion element in this group would immediately force your ring to be characteristic 2. On the other hand, if $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^{\infty}}]$ denotes the ring of integers in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})$, obtained as the union of all fields $\mathbb{Q}( \zeta_{p^n} )$ for all integers $n \geq 1$, you probably have your group as an index 2 subgroup of the unit group of this ring (because of $-1$). I don't see an immediate way to get an equality on the nose

@Mike: this is not correct, there are other units (and you mean $\zeta_{p^{\infty}}$ resp. $\zeta_{p^n}$), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_unit.

You are correct; I was only thinking of the torsion part, ignoring the free part - how silly. I'm not sure what you mean by the second part of your comment, however
